# JOLT Transformation Merge Array of Objects

Tags: jolt

I am trying to create a jolt transformation for the below input;

```
{
"group1": [
    {
        "schema": "schemaA"
    },
    {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2"
    }
],
"group2": [
    {
        "schema": "schemaA"
    },
    {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2"
    }
]}
```

With the desired output of;

```
{
"group1": {
    "schema": "schemaA",
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
},
"group2": {
    "schema": "schemaA",
    "key1": "val1",
    "key2": "val2"
}}
```

The key 'schema' will always be present but I won't know what the key1,key2,etc values are. So I can't explicitly map them. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spec,

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "group*": {
        "*": {
          "key*": "&2.&",
          "schema": "&2.&"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```