# JOLT - Merge objects in an array based on a common key-value

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have this input JSON:

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "foo_name": "jack",
      "id": 123,
      "some_attr1": "val1"
    },
    {
      "foo_name": "bob",
      "id": 456,
      "some_other_attr1": "val2"
    },
    {
      "foo_name": "jack",
      "cool_attr1": "val3",
      "not_cool_attr1": "val4",
      "some_attr1": "vvaaalllllll"
    }
  ]
}
```

The desired output is:

```json
{
  "people": [
    {
      "foo_name": "jack",
      "id": 123,
      "some_attr1": "val1", // in case of common keys, grab the first one
      "cool_attr1": "val3", // order of merged keys does not matter
      "not_cool_attr1": "val4"
    },
    {
      "foo_name": "bob",
      "id": 456,
      "some_other_attr1": "val2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where keys in the object `"foo_name": "jack"` gets merged.  Order of the keys does not matter.  The value `jack` is *not* known ahead of time.

What I tried so far:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "people": { // only the people array
        "*": { // foreach item
          "foo_name": { // group by foo_name
            "*": {
              "@2": "&[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Similar questions:

1. [JOLT Transformation Merge Array of Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004909/jolt-transformation-merge-array-of-objects)
2. [JOLT Transformation Merge Array of multi Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70753154/jolt-transformation-merge-array-of-multi-objects)
3. [Jolt Transform: Merging objects with more than 1 similar fields and 2 dissimilar fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67792364/jolt-transform-merging-objects-with-more-than-1-similar-fields-and-2-dissimilar)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following transformation spec

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "people": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2.@1,foo_name.&" // group by foo_names
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": { // indexes of people array
          "*": "&2[#2].&"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // pick only the first components among members
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "*": "ONE"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

This spec will do it.  Need to

1. Group every item in the `people` array by `foo_name`.
2. Merge. For duplicate keys, values will be treated as arrays.
3. `cardinality` assigns ONE for every key.
4. Get rid of the object-value groupings and put it inside the `people` array.

---

```
[
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "people": {
            "*": {
              "foo_name": {
                "*": {
                  "@2": "&[]"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
        },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "*": { // foreach group
            "*": { // foreach item in array
              "*": "&2.&" // merge
            }
          }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "cardinality",
        "spec": {
          "*": { // foreach group
            "*": "ONE" // grab the first item
          }
        }
    },
    {
        "operation": "shift",
        "spec": {
          "*": "people[]"
        }
    }
]
```